# pop up modal on delete button not working with java script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i cant figure out where is the problem! when i check a checkbox it deletes the data but not showing the modal and when i press the button with checkboxs checked it shows the modal!
any idea?

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id02').modal('show');";
        echo "$('.delete2').click(function(){";
            foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox ){
                $sql = "DELETE FROM `uploading` WHERE id=$checkbox";
                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    header("location:read.php");
                }
            }
        echo  "});
    });</script>";
}
```

Comment: This is a mess start over and separate server side code with your client side code. its very easy

Comment: I'll suggest you to separate serverside code to the client side. You mash up jquery and php and it's not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I think your php code will be above the jQuery CDN or jQuery file, you need to call php script after the jQuery file. Hope you understand.

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: I am assuming that problem may because of following reason
1: $_POST['delete'] is the name of button. You are using header(location) may be issue due to this. May be JQUERY CDN is below your code.etc. you need to share your HTML script to.